# Как сослаться на n аргумент функции, если количество аргументов неизвестно?

Tags: php, функции

Как сослаться на n аргумент функции, если количество аргументов неизвестно?

```
<?php
function foo()
{
$kolvo=func_num_args ();
echo "Количество людей: <b>",$kolvo ,"</b><br/>";
for ($x=0;$x<$kolvo;$x++)
    {
        echo "Добрый день ", **"что сюда вставлять?"**,"<br/>";
    }
}
foo("Вася","Петя","Таня","Маня");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php
или конкретно:
http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list